# What are the differences between calling context.Users and context.Set<User>?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext, dbset

Deepening my knowledge in ASP.NET, I have a question that arises from the following class:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Route> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

What is the difference under the hood between using `context.Routes` and using `context.Set<Route>()`?

I verified that the two instances are not equal in the following way

```
Console.WriteLine(context.Routes.Equals(context.Set<Route>()))
```

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224130/how-does-dbset-actually-work-under-the-hood) but I still haven't resolved my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, while both `context.Routes` and `context.Set<Route>()` access Route entities, they differ in their nature and purpose.  First of all, `context.Routes` is a single, persistent collection within the context, tracking changes for saving. On the other hand,  `context.Set<Route>()` creates temporary sets for specific operations, not affecting the main collection or tracking changes. Choose context.Routes for general interactions and persistence, and context.Set<Route>() for temporary queries without modifying the main collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was the kind of answer I was looking for. Feel free to create one and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm glad to assist on this. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the differences between calling context.Users and
> context.Set?

Well, based on your scenario and description, while both `context.Routes` and `context.Set<Route>()` access Route entities, they differ in their nature and purpose. First of all, context.Routes is a single, persistent collection within the context, tracking changes for saving. On the other hand, `context.Set<Route>()` creates temporary sets for specific operations, not affecting the main collection or tracking changes. Choose context.Routes for general interactions and persistence, and `context.Set<Route>()` for temporary queries without modifying the main collection.

Therefore, if you need to work with entity types dynamically or if you have a reference to the entity type as a Type object, then `context.Set<TEntity>()` might be more appropriate.

**Note:** In addition, you could [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1?view=efcore-8.0) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Route> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

And you can call it any time like

```cs
var ctx = new AppDbContext();
var list = ctx.Routes.Where(....);
```

But what if you have some generic code?

```cs
public void DoSomething<T>(DbContext ctx)
{
    var list = ctx.Set<T>().Where(...);
}
```

In other words, this is different because in the first case you use a concrete implementation and in the second case you're flexible and can use different implementations of Context.

*"What is the difference **under the hood** between using..."*

Under the hood only one difference. `Set<T>()` dynamically finds property of the concrete instance and makes call against that. You can see implementation yourself if you use a tool like `dotPeek`

Comment: I understand what I should do in case of genericity. My doubt goes further. For example, the DbContext.Set method explains that "...creates a DbSet<TEntity> for a shared-type entity type...". Does this bring any deficiency when creating multiple or different DbSets<Route> instances? We normally inject the DbContext dependency as Scoped. Does using different instances of DbSets<Route> during a request have any negative effects?

Comment: @ldiaz997 Db context is designed as Unit of Work pattern. You should worry about making too many calls on the same instance of DbContext. Your scenario should be - add model, add related models and save, dispose. For select also, don't keep same DB context around. Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/